# Meaning of 'review' in 'Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!'

Tags: support, flagging

Recently, one of my flag *duplicate* was declined. I google it and I was in other questions that the warning *Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!* remains until more of 90% of the flags in the last seven days result *helpful*.

However I don't really understand the word *review* in the worning. Is it suppose to mean that I should look at the flags that I gave or is it suppose to mean that I should send a review of the declined flag explaining why I flagged it as duplicated?

Comment: I *think* they mean you should go back and look at your past behaviour to improve on it (i.e. a generic *review* in the sense of 1 in https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/review). I guess this is more relevant for the busier pages like SO or Math.SE where there are many and hotly disputed/contested flags. I don't think there is a lot you can or should do. A general advice on this site (maybe contrary to how others do it) is to be patient and lenient with duplicates. Suggest a duplicate in the comments and don't flag. Wait for a response and if the OP agrees it's duplicate, flag away...

Comment: ... Otherwise try to work out why the OP thinks it's not a duplicate and find a solution. Normally this site does not get flooded like other SE sites and I don't think we have a problem with low-quality answers to possible duplicates, so we can certainly afford wait a bit before closing a question as duplicate.

Comment: Ok, understood.